# How to name the quote character in French

Tags: traduction, anglais, typographie, terminologie

What is the quote character called in French? I'm coming from a computer programming perspective and am writing technical documentation.

I specifically mean the `"` character and not `«`/`»` (guillemet) etc.

For the moment I am using the English word ‘quote’, but would like to know if there is something else.

Comment: Im working in IS/IT field in Paris and Id recommend referring to it as "double quote" (or "guillemet double"), as quote or "guillemet" could be confused with the ' character.

Answer (score 13):

L’Office québécois de la langue française has a [very good description](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3363) of all quotation marks that can be used in French :

> Sauf exception, les guillemets s’emploient par paires, les guillemets ouvrants («) accompagnant les guillemets fermants (»). Il existe plusieurs sortes de guillemets, qui peuvent tous être utilisés dans un même texte si ce dernier comporte des citations dans les citations. On utilise ainsi, dans l’ordre, les guillemets français, anglais, puis allemands pour marquer les différents niveaux de citations.
>
> **Exemple** :
>
> - Voici comment le journaliste rapporte ses propos et ceux de la députée : « J’avais fait la déclaration suivante au bulletin de nouvelles : ‘‘Elle a accusé le ministre d’être ‘menteur et hypocrite’ à la Chambre des communes.’’ Ce n’est donc pas moi qui ai traité le ministre de menteur et d’hypocrite, mais bien la députée. »
>
> Ces différents types de guillemets appellent quelques précisions.
>
> Les guillemets français (« »), appelés abusivement *chevrons* à cause de leur forme, sont ceux que l’on utilise normalement dans un texte français. Une espace insécable sépare les guillemets ouvrants et fermants du texte guillemeté.
>
> Les guillemets anglais (‘‘ ’’) se présentent sous la forme de doubles apostrophes dont la première paire est à l’envers; on fait parfois la distinction entre guillemets anglais (‘‘ ’’) et guillemets américains (" "), aussi appelés *petits guillemets*. On ne met pas d’espace entre le texte ainsi guillemeté et ces guillemets.
>
> Les guillemets allemands se présentent généralement sous la forme d’apostrophes simples (‘ ’) ou (' '). Il n’y a pas d’espace entre le texte ainsi guillemeté et ces guillemets.

Comment: Le _Lexique des règles typograhiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale_ parle de « guillemets ouvrants » et de « guillemets fermants », et précise : « ...on n'emploiera qu'exceptionnellement dans un texte français les **guillemets anglais ouvrants (“) et fermants (”)**.

Comment: oui là on a un avis québecois

Comment: J'ai vu appelé quelque part („ “) des guillemets allemands, est-ce que ça a quelque chose de vrai ?

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas Les allemands utilisent les guillemets de cette façon (ouvrant en bas, fermant en haut), mais si je ne m'abuse, utilisent le style apostrophe simple.

Comment: Est-ce que tu veux dire comme ‚ceci‛ ? Est-ce que ce n'est pas tout à fait horrible d'avoir des virgules collées du mauvais côté ?

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas Oui, mais ce ne doit pas l'être trop si c'est ce à quoi on est habitué.

Comment: J'ai toujours vu des guillemets doubles inversés en allemand („Hallo!“).

Comment: Je doute que *guillemets américain* soit compris par plus de 1% des programmeurs. Seul *guillemet droit double* ou *guillemet double ASCII* est sans ambiguïté et sera compris sans hésitation par la plupart d'entre eux.

Answer (score 10):

La [FAQ Typo](http://listetypo.free.fr/ortho/guillemets.html) donne

- *guillemet dactylo*, *chiures de mouche*<sup>1</sup> utilisés par les typographes,
- *guillemet droit* utilisé par ceux qui font de la P.A.O

---

The FAQ of the typography mailing gives:

- *guillemet dactylo*, *chiures de mouche* used by typographs,
- *guillemet droit* used by people doing computer aided publishing

---

(1) au pluriel bien que la FAQ le donne au singulier, [d'autres sources](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/gallerie-guillemet.html) utilisent *chiure de mouche* au singulier pour `'` (alias *apostrophe dactylo* ou *apostrophe droite*) par opposition à une apostrophe courbe `’`. Je ne sais pas si le singulier résulte d'une erreur dans la FAQ ou d'une divergence de vocabulaire.

Answer (score 7):

For programming documentation, use *guillemet double* for `"`. Do not use *guillemet droit* as this could be interpreted as a single quote `'`. There is no other ASCII character that could be called a *guillemet double*, but there are other Unicode characters: `“` and `”` (opening and closing double quotes, not found on keyboards but automatically inserted when you press <kbd>"</kbd> in some word processing software) and `«` and `»` (opening and closing French quotes, found on Canadian French keyboards). It's unlikely that programmers would think of anything but `"` for *guillemet double*, but if you need to reinforce the choice of character, you can say *guillemet droit double* or *guillemet double symétrique*, and explain how to type it.

Don't use the English word *quote*. Not every French programmer would understand the word.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution is probably to use "[guillemets droits](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet)". Of course, you'll want to show the actual character where you define it. See for example the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) (where they use *guillemets doubles*, which seems [rather common](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cha%C3%AEne_de_caract%C3%A8res#Sucre_syntaxique)).

Comment: Quelqu'un connaît(-il) l'index glycémique du sucre syntaxique ?

Comment: I don't know, but it is reputed to give the semicolon cancer.

Answer (score 3):

In French, *guillemet* basically means the same thing as *quote* in English.  I'd simply loan the English word *doublequote* to clarify that you're talking about `"` and not `« »`.

You could also say *les guillemets doubles*, but I don't know how widespread its usage is or how many would understand what you meant.

Comment: *Guillemet double* is more likely to be understood than *double quote*.